# Server hangs - rtorrent

Tags: slackware, torrent

I have server with torrent clients. I run 20 torrent clients - rtorrent. Some times server  hangs. How can I find problem - why server is hangs?

I use Slackware linux 12.2. On hard disk I use ext3 and ext4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the problem with the usual tools -- logs, dmesg, top, strace, maybe a little tcpdump.